# Loop throuth a filtered list in vue.js with parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, parameter-passing

How to loop in vue.js through a filtered list with an input parameter given?

Pls. take into consideration that filtering like `<li v-for="x in todos_filtered" v-if="x.person == 'Mike'">` should be avoided with many records.

Here the code which returns an empty list instead of 2 elements.

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="x in todos_filtered('Mike')">
      {{ x.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>

<script>
myObject = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {  
    todos: [
      { person: 'Mike', text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
      { person: 'Luke', text: 'Learn Vue.js' },
      { person: 'Mike', text: 'Build Something Awesome' }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    todos_filtered(person) {
      return this.todos.filter((x) => x.person === person);
    }
  },
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed property should return a function that take the `person` as parameter:

```js
  computed: {
    todos_filtered() {
      return (person)=> this.todos.filter((x) => x.person === person);
    }
  },
```